# Installing vtk in python

Tags: python, installation, pip, vtk

The VTK package has [recently been made available for `pip`](http://prabhuramachandran.blogspot.com/2018/01/vtk-810-wheels-for-all-platforms-on-pypi.html), but when I try to run `pip install --user --upgrade vtk` (or with `pip3`) on Ubuntu 14.04, all I get is:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement vtk in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
Downloading/unpacking vtk
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for vtk in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ignacio/.pip/pip.log
```

and the log file shows:

```
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/vtk/
URLs to search for versions for vtk in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/vtk/
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/vtk/
  ...
  Skipping https://pypi.python.org/packages/13/7f/735fbc0dd78c91ad3693cfdfe5c91603899fc8e24909f935d46d2fde6559/vtk-8.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=49c8d620b2affe2dc2284048659115e5 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/vtk/) because it is not compatible with this Python
  ...
```

But I surely have CPython 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 (or that's what they say), and I've installed other packages with `pip`/`pip3`. What could be the reasons it "is not compatible with this Python"?

The output of `python -c "from pip import pep425tags;print(pep425tags.supported_tags)"` includes `('cp27', 'cp27mu', 'manylinux1_x86_64')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had seen the solution suggested for this kind of issues:

```
$ pip install --update pip
```

And I had updated `pip` before, of course. It turns out that the new `pip` version was not being used, probably because I had installed it for the user, not for the system.

So at the end it worked by using `python -m pip` instead of just `pip`:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade --user vtk
```

And then:

```
$ python -c 'import vtk ; print vtk.vtkVersion.GetVTKVersion()'
8.1.0
```